# How do I use row_number() with partitioning and without ordering?

Tags: mysql, sql, row-number

My table looks like :

table_1

```
| Id | Num |
| 1  | 1   |
| 2  | 1   |
| 3  | 1   |
| 4  | 2   |
| 5  | 1   |
| 6  | 2   |
| 7  | 2   |
```

I want a row_number next to 'num' column, but as soon as the num changes it's value, the row_number resets.

I want my table to look like:

```
| Id | Num | row_num |
| 1  | 1   | 1 |
| 2  | 1   | 2 | 
| 3  | 1   | 3 |
| 4  | 2   | 1 |
| 5  | 1   | 1 |
| 6  | 2   | 1 |
| 7  | 2   | 2 |
```

Comment: What do you mean by *without sorting*? Probably you might want to show us what you expect your numbering to look like.

Comment: | Id | Num | row_num

| 1 | 1 | 1 |

| 2 | 1 | 2 |

| 3 | 1 | 3 |

| 4 | 2 | 1 |

| 5 | 1 | 1 |

| 6 | 2 | 1 |

| 7 | 2 | 2 |

Apologies, I mean "ordering"

Answer (score 1):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  For this version, the simplest solution is probably to identify the islands using the difference of row numbers:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by seqnum - seqnum_2 order by id) as row_num
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by num order by id) as seqnum_2
      from table_1 t
     ) t;
```

If you run the subquery, you will see how the difference identifies the "adjacent" values of `num`.

Note:  If (as in your example) the `id`s are sequential with no gaps, you can simplify this to:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by id - seqnum_2 order by id) as row_num
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by num order by id) as seqnum_2
      from table_1 t
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

With MySQl 8 you can do this:

```
select Id, Num, Row_Number() over (order by (Select 0)) as row_num from table_1;
```